# Hired by a person who was already set to change positions

Tags: hiring-process

I've recently started a new job.
I went from a consultancy job to full-time employment at a company I already had experience with, for a job I enjoy.

My issue isn't at all with the job, I'm quite happy with how everything works out, however there's a big question mark hanging over me right now and I'm unsure on the implications.

I was contacted for the job, and hired by, who I assumed would then be my direct manager.
Having worked with him a few months prior, this was a of the appeal of the job.
However, it turns out that he has been moved to head up a different department.
Furthermore, he knew this was going to happen before he even sent me the job offer.

Am I in a safe situation?
Is being hired just before a managerial change a red flag?
Is this a common occurence in large firms?

I'm not sure if I should spend my first days asking around about this, for fear of how it might come across.

Comment: It's only a red flag if the company is being cavalier about it since you have a right to worry. Your manager will have a significant impact on your job after all. [This](http://www.inc.com/alison-green/should-you-accept-a-job-offer-when-there-s-no-manager-in-place-yet.html) might be a useful article to read.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, congratulations for having a new job.

To answer your questions,

> Is this a common occurence in large firms?

My first job was with one of the Dow Jones 30 companies. On the first day I reported to work, they told me to report to Ms.X whom I never met before. Later on that day, I learned that the manager who interviewed me and hired me was transferred to another department the same day I arrived. A few months later, I was told the hiring manager hired me to fill a position that was supposed to be filled 6 months before I was hired.

> Is being hired just before a managerial change a red flag?

No, I don't think so. You are a new hire. You were not involved with any real power struggle/office politics yet. Put it in another way, you are somewhat innocent.

> Am I in a safe situation?

That will depend on your performance in the next few months or years. Just concentrate on your new job. Work hard to prove that the hiring manager hired you for good reasons.. Your new manager will like you and keep you.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words. However this wasn't just the hiring manager, I had also worked with him for a 5 month period prior to accepting the job. Which is in part what prompted him to hire me. Regardless, it's good to know others have had similar experiences, I've so far been limited to small firms and contracting work.

Comment: @Reaces The best advice I can give you is to work hard. If you are worried that you are seen as the hiring manager's people, working hard can prove it toyour manager that the hiring manager hired you for reasons.

Comment: @Reaces I made slight edit to my answer to respond to your comment above.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate all the advice! I just found out I might be in managerial limbo for a few months as they look for a replacement... So my concerns might be unwarranted / far future.

Comment: @Reaces Well you do need to (help) resolve that *managerial limbo* a.s.a.p. because that could be bad: people should know about you and the work you do, and give you direction (either because you seek it or because they feel like it).

Comment: @JanDoggen I still have one functional manager, even though he can't really approve anything / give evaluations and feedback, he is assigning me work and making sure people find out who I am and what kind of work to send my way. So in that regard I'm covered.

Comment: @Jan Doggen is right: managerial limbos are potentially dangerous. Do every task they ask you to do and ask for more when you're done. Try to be as visible as possible.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I in a safe situation?

There's no real way to know for sure until you are in the job.

But, based on my experience, large companies all have formal processes for generating a requisition to hire a new employee, get budget approvals, and handle the hiring process. Thus, others beside the hiring manager know and have approved of your hire. To me, there seems to be little obvious risk here.

> Is being hired just before a managerial change a red flag?

Probably not. Most likely thee two events - your hiring and your manager's moving to a different department have absolutely no connection.

While it's a bit awkward for you (you now have a boss whom you haven't yet met), it's probably not much different than if your boss had transferred a year down the road. It might even be better. You'll just have to wait to find out.

> Is this a common occurence in large firms?

Large firms have reorgs and transfers all the time. And large firms hire new employees all the time.

Given that, it's not unusual for a hiring manager to hire a new employee and be transferred, both within a short time period.

> I'm not sure if I should spend my first days asking around about this,
>   for fear of how it might come across.

I suspect you are worrying unnecessarily. Only time will tell for sure. Worrying about it now and asking around your first days won't help or change anything.

Try to put it out of your mind and assume it's just an inconsequential coincidence. You want to go into your new job with all of your positive energy concentrated on starting off well.

Comment: Reading through your other answers on the site I have to say you have some pretty great advice out there! Thank you for taking the time to write these up!